# Как сделать что бы появлялось фото если значение input равно определенному слову?

Tags: javascript, input

Я новичок и хотел бы узнать, как сделать так чтобы когда пользователь вводил секретное слово в окно ввода данных и нажимал на кнопку OK, то на сайте появлялось фото.

Comment: Боюсь, это скорее задание, нежели конкретный вопрос. Опишите, как вы пытались решить свою задачу и с какими трудностями столкнулись?

Comment: https://learn.javascript.ru/ Я бы удалил вопрос и пошел учить жс :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Пример, от которого можно оттолкнуться:

```js
const img = document.querySelector("img")
const input = document.querySelector("input")
const button = document.querySelector("button")

const secret = "секрет"

const handleClick = () => {
  const value = input.value.trim()
  if (!value) {
    console.log("введите слово")
    return
  }  
  if (value === secret) {
    img.classList.toggle("hide")
  } else {
    console.log("неугадали, попробуте еще раз")
  }
}

button.addEventListener("click", handleClick)
```

```css
img {
  display: block;
}

.hide {
  display: none;
}
```

```html
<input />
<button>OK</button>
<img class="hide" src="https://picsum.photos/200" />
```